# How to add a new row into DataGridView and fill it with data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This is my code

```
Public Sub InvoicItmCall()

    'If IteDataTb.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    SellingDGView.Rows.Add()

    SellingDGView.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value = SellingDGView.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value + 1
    SellingDGView.Rows.Item(0).Cells(1).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(0).Item("IteFName")
    SellingDGView.Rows.Item(0).Cells(2).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(0).Item("IteFSizeUnit")
    SellingDGView.Rows.Item(0).Cells(4).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(0).Item("IteFSellpris")
    SellingDGView.Rows.Item(0).Cells(6).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(0).Item("IteVat")

    'Dim unused = SellingDGView.Rows.Add(rows)

End Sub
```

Right now, the code works fine and fills the first row on the grid, this is for a barcode scanner. When I scan one barcode, it fills the row with the appropriate data. However, when I scan another code, it overwrites the older row.

I want it to add a new row and add the other data to it.

So when I scan a different item after the first one, it should fill up a new row.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I have found a workaround

```
    If IteDataTb.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row As DataRow In IteDataTb.Rows
            SellingDGView.Rows.Add(row.Item("IteFName"), row.Item("IteFSizeUnit"), row.Item("IteFSellpris"), row.Item("IteVat"))
        Next row
    End If
```

This creates a new row every time and fills it. But now I want to fill specific cells.

How do I do that?

Right now it fills everything inappropriately.

Comment: *"I would guess you need to get the index of the newly added row"*. Which is exactly what that `Add` method returns. This is an example of what happens when you don't read the documentation or at least pay attention to Intellisense. Not an unusual example, but an example nonetheless.

Comment: Of course, an even better idea would be to call the overload of `Add` that takes an `Object` array containing the cell values, so the whole lot would collapse to a single line of code. Another thing that could be discovered by reading the documentation.

Comment: Having said all that, it rather looks like the data is coming from a `DataTable` in the first place. It's hard to say for sure but I'd guess that the "proper" solution would be to have that table bound to the grid in the first place.

Comment: Check my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do it the way you originally were, I'd do it like this:

```vb
Dim index = SellingDGView.Rows.Add()
Dim newRow = SellingDGView.Rows(index)
'Dim newRow = SellingDGView.Rows(SellingDGView.Rows.Add())
Dim dataRow = IteDataTb.Rows(0)

newRow.Cells(0).Value = SellingDGView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value + 1
newRow.Cells(1).Value = dataRow("IteFName")
newRow.Cells(2).Value = dataRow("IteFSizeUnit")
newRow.Cells(4).Value = dataRow("IteFSellpris")
newRow.Cells(6).Value = dataRow("IteVat")
```

If you wanted to use the more appropriate overload of `Add` that I mentioned and you used in your second example:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In IteDataTb.Rows
    SellingDGView.Rows.Add(SellingDGView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value + 1,
                           row("IteFName"),
                           row("IteFSizeUnit"),
                           Nothing,
                           row("IteFSellpris"),
                           Nothing,
                           row("IteVat"))
Next
```

The `If` statement is pointless.

Also, I doubt that you're getting the next ID in the best way with that expression that adds 1 but that's a different question.

Comment: I appreciate taking the time to solve this issue. It works great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every time that you need a new row, you can do as follows:

```
        Dim i As Integer = SellingDGView.Rows.Add()

        SellingDGView.Rows.Item(i).Cells(0).Value = i
        SellingDGView.Rows.Item(i).Cells(1).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(j).Item("IteFName")
        SellingDGView.Rows.Item(i).Cells(2).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(j).Item("IteFSizeUnit")
        SellingDGView.Rows.Item(i).Cells(4).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(j).Item("IteFSellpris")
        SellingDGView.Rows.Item(i).Cells(6).Value = IteDataTb.Rows(j).Item("IteVat")
```

Herein, I've assumed that the variable "j" indicates to your desired row in IteDataTb datagridview. I mean that you should control the "j" variable yourself. I can help you if know more about the IteDataTb.